# When migrating from a production server to a live one while using wordpress how should I go about doing this?

Tags: wordpress, database-migration

I am wondering if I can just export/import the SQL and then copy the folder to the new server or do I need to deactivate the plugins or how to do this? I don't want to mess up my current site in the production server just to find myself in a worse position.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Wordpress for about a year now, and I haven't found an easy way to move the setup. You have to move the database, and you have to move the folder with all supporting files (uploads, etc). I would just use the export feature of wordpress to download an XML and then import it on your prod install. Move the folders via ftp.

Comment: would you recommend me to install a fresh copy of Wordpress in the new server? or just move everything there via FTP?

Comment: Fresh install, just import all your posts, and move the uploads into the new install. Moving manually is a pain, there might be references broken, so you'd have to go and make sure all of your config files are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "[moving wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)" official instructions?